# How to use this result of this function with the # symbol?

Tags: output-formatting

I typed in the following expression to yield the roots of a quaternionic quadratic equation, since the entire argument concerns only the real part:

g=(n^2)*cot^2(t)-(1/(4n^2))(h^2tan^2(t)+sin^2(t)), solve for t

From which it returned a closed form solution (which is great), that I have no idea how to read:

Given n = 3, g = 2, h =5, tell me how I would solve for theta (solve for t) with the solution provided by Wolfram.  Thanks.

[![enter image description here][1]]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGfRR.png
For instance, here I entered g,n,h = 3,7,5:

[![enter image description here][2]]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w98Jx.png

Clearly 1/n is factored out, resulting the expression sqrt(x^6-110x^5...) etc, where did the -110 come from?

Forcing a displayed resolution for t, I have found, that for any real g,h,n, that there always exists two conjugate real numbers (opposite signs of each other) that satisfy theta (satisfy t), which is expected since they represent the accepted solution to the two roots of a quaternionic quadratic equation:

[[image]]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: You are showing Wolfram alpha outputs. This forum is for Wolfram Mathematica not Wolfram alpha. So hard to help you since I do not use Wolfram alpha and can only reproduce things using Wolfram Mathematica.  If you use Wolfram Mathematica, it will be easier to compare things.

Answer (score 3):

> that I have no idea how to read:

You can either use `N` on it or use `ToRadicals`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq = g == n^2*Cot[t]^2 - 1/(4*n^2)*(h^2*Tan[t]^2 + Sin[t]^2)
```

Looking at first solution (as there are many)

```
sol = First@Solve[eq /. {n -> 3, g -> 2, h -> 5}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now do

```
N[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
ToRadicals[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What I'm asking: If I had pencil and paper, and set c1 to 1 or zero, with n,g,h equal to 3,2,5,    what would I write in pencil and paper.  

What is the arithmetic form of that for those n,g,h, because whatever this form is, the closed form solution to a general quadratic equation over the quaternions.

You can see this result at the bottom of the second to last page in this link, where I derive the general case. It's the last step of the derivation, but I do not know how to read it.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/16pnQXR84eUp-Zgaw0zgPGBANxCffoZ5UB0iSVzrrSTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For instance, here I used g,n,h = 3,7,5

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq = g == n^2*Cot[t]^2 - 1/(4*n^2)*(h^2*Tan[t]^2 + Sin[t]^2);
```

The result that you highlighted says that there are periodic roots (period of `2 Pi`) with base values at about `2*0.931267` and `-2*0.931267`, i.e., at about `1.86253` and `-1.86253`.

```
sol = Solve[eq /. {n -> 7, g -> 3, h -> 5}, t, Reals] // N
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[(eq[[-1]] - eq[[1]]) /. {n -> 7, g -> 3, h -> 5}], {t, -2, 2},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{t, 0} /. sol /. C[1] -> 0]}]
```

[image]

The solutions are periodic.

Although the roots are presented as four roots having a period of `2 Pi`, they could be represented as two roots having a period of `Pi`

```
sol /. C[1] -> 0 /. r_Real :> r + Pi

(* {{t -> 1.86253}, {t -> 4.42065}, {t -> 1.27906}, {t -> 5.00413}} *)

sol /. C[1] -> 1

(* {{t -> 5.00413}, {t -> 7.56224}, {t -> 4.42065}, {t -> 8.14572}} *)
```

Note that the second and fourth root of the first set are the same as the first and third roots of the second set.

Graphically, the period is `Pi`

```
Plot[Evaluate[(eq[[-1]] - eq[[1]]) /. {n -> 7, g -> 3, 
    h -> 5}], {t, -6, 6},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{t, 0} /. sol /. C[1] -> #] & /@ {-1, 0, 1}},
 GridLines -> {{-1, 0, 1} Pi, None}]
```

[image]